# Key binding for "Terminate and Relaunch" not working

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I created a key binding for the "Terminate and Relaunch" command in eclipse, but when hitting the key combination the command is not executed. I set "When:" to "In Dialogs and Windows". Any ideas why the keybinding for this command is not working?

My setup: I'm using Spring Tool Suite 3.4.0.RELEASE, which is based on eclipse 4.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

I think although the wording is equivalent, they're both unrelated. I noticed the Relaunch button on toolbar came from spring plugin / STS, but "Terminate and Relaunch" function is there even without spring plugin.

As to what's the original purpose of this function I still have no clue